# htaccess for codeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a user to `/hd/142` if they don't have `/hd/` in the URL. I've tried so many options and most of them just redirected me over and over again.  Here is the current `.htaccess` that I have setup.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js)
RewriteRule ^hd/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(images|css|js)/(.*) /applicationFiles/$1/$2 [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if url does not have hd in it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hd/ [NC]
#redirect to hd
RewriteRule ^  /hd/142 [L,R=301]  

#existing rules
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js) [NC]
RewriteRule ^hd/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(images|css|js)/(.*) /applicationFiles/$1/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use routes.php in codeigniter:

```
$route['^(hd)'] = '/hd/142';
```

Read more under the Regular Expressions section here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html